# How to update clients when database is edited outside of feathersjs app

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I have two server-side applications editing the same database.

One server is a feathersjs app and another is a simple nodejs app. A frontend app connects to the feathersjs app via feathersjs client.

How, when the nodejs app edits the database, can I update clients connected to the feathersjs app? As currently any changes made outside the featherjs app aren't reflected on the feathersjs clients.

Can I trigger the patched event somehow and force the clients to pull down the updated data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using mongodb with WiredTiger storageEngine you can use the collection.watch() function and add a monitor in your feathers app something like this

```
   //src/services/monitor.js 
   module.exports = function(app){
      //get mongo client
      const mongoClient = app.get('mongoClient');
      //connect db
      mongoClient.then(db => {

        //collection to watch
        const collection = db.collection('your_collection_name')

        //watch collection
        const changeStream = collection.watch({ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });

        //on some data changed
        changeStream.on('change', data => {
          console.log ( 'something is changed in your collection' , data )
          //your service.emit
        });
      })
    }
```

Then I added this simple monitor in the `/src/services/index.js` (maybe not the right way but it works)

```
//src/services/index.js
...
const monitor = require('./monitor.js');
module.exports = function (app) {
   ...
   app.configure(monitor);
   ...
};
```

Data returned on every change on the collection

```
{ _id:
   { _data:
      '825C7F03230000001C29295A100490DEF2C65812410FABF0DE46F9C89D7246645F696400645C1AC097B189CBD5D4A24D330004' },
  operationType: 'replace',
  clusterTime:
   Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 28, high_: 1551827747 },
  fullDocument:
   { _id: 5c1ac097b189cbd5d4a24d33,
     id: '12',
     language: 'it-IT',
     category: 'some data',
     slug: '',
     description: 'some data',
     src:'',
     color: 'card',
     status: true,
     home: true,
     order_int: '3',
     visual: 'card' },
  ns: { db: 'mydb', coll: 'mycollection' },
  documentKey: { _id: 5c1ac097b189cbd5d4a24d33 } }
```

More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, only changes made through the Feathers API will be reflected but on the server you can always emit the event you need via [service.emit](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#emiteventname-data):

```
dbConnection.on('someDatabaseUpdate', data => {
  app.service('messages').emit('patched', data);
  app.service('messages').emit('updated', data);
});
```

Things to note here (also discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb/issues/76)):

- There will be no user or any other information about the method call
- `data` will not be run through any service hooks